# position sticky doesnt work inside a container but fixed position does?

Tags: css

I am trying to make an element sticky and having no luck. The element is the `bd-right-wrapper`If I make the element `fixed` then it stays, but not as sticky. I have read other SO articles about how to remove `overflow` on the container, set `left:0` etc but none have any effect. What am I missing?

### DEMO

```css
.split-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: black;}

.split-left {
    background-image: url("xyz.jpg"), url("xyzz.jpg");
    background-repeat: repeat, no-repeat;
    background-size: auto,cover;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/ /* tried with and without overflow<< this is comment not in my real code*/
    border-radius: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
    position: relative;} /* tried with and without position relative<< this comment is not in my real code*/

.bd-right-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    padding: 20px 0 10px 15px;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;}

.split-right{
     border-radius: 20px;
     display: flex;
     overflow: hidden;}
```

```html
 <div class=col-sm-12 split-wrapper>
  <div class=col-sm-12 split-left>
    <div class="bd-right-wrapper">
    //content
    </div>
    <div class="split-wrapper">
    //content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Comments in CSS must be wrapped in `/* comment here */`. CSS does not have line comments, only block comments.

Comment: Sorry I dont understand what you mean?

Comment: Your demo CSS code is *invalid CSS* because you are using `// comments` which CSS does not support.

Comment: this is not in the code, only for SO

Comment: Please consider changing the comments to `/* multiline style comments */`, as the code snippet will not properly work with invalid syntax.

Comment: done completely above

Comment: Your HTML is invalid as well. You are missing quotes around the first two div's classes. You don't have a style for the child `split-wrapper` - I'm guessing this should be `split-right`

Answer (score 0):

Even though you had a bunch of invalid markup and CSS, I'm guessing this is what you're after:

1. `.split-wrapper` is the parent flex elmement
2. `.split-left` and `split-right` are the two immediate children
3. `.bd-right-wrapper` is a child of `split-left` and is a `sticky` element. This element needs to have the class sticky, since the parent will stretch the entire height of its parent.

I added some basic `flex` properties to the `split-left` and `split-right` so you can see it working.

```css
.split-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.split-left {
  flex: 0 0 20%;
}

.split-right {
  flex: 0 0 80%;
}

.bd-right-wrapper {
  padding: 20px 0 10px 15px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-12 split-wrapper">
  <div class="col-sm-12 split-left">
    <div class="bd-right-wrapper">
      I'm sticky
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="split-right">
    Pharetra eros mi eros accumsan dui. Pellentesque ipsum iaculis. Mi neque in nonummy venenatis vestibulum. Class egestas adipiscing nisl tellus quam ut in amet. Nostra nunc leo lorem eget ipsum elit eget metus nam sed pede. Nam nibh risus sit dui nullam.
    Consequat luctus tempus. Pede tellus eu mattis morbi donec. Natoque class leo. Ac lacus vestibulum ac odio ac. Risus lorem mauris. Proin enim tortor at erat dui. Aliquam magna condimentum. Orci donec morbi. Id justo at malesuada erat nulla urna quam
    eu nec elit commodo mi voluptatum gravida ante bibendum justo. Eleifend nec eget. Id massa quis eu vitae elit. Bibendum interdum semper. Donec libero duis. Phasellus malesuada adipiscing qui et eu. Justo egestas erat auctor sagittis sed nonummy amet
    dolor et in id. Ut blandit justo. Donec fringilla cursus enim velit ullamcorper. Pharetra eros mi eros accumsan dui. Pellentesque ipsum iaculis. Mi neque in nonummy venenatis vestibulum. Class egestas adipiscing nisl tellus quam ut in amet. Nostra
    nunc leo lorem eget ipsum elit eget metus nam sed pede. Nam nibh risus sit dui nullam. Consequat luctus tempus. Pede tellus eu mattis morbi donec. Natoque class leo. Ac lacus vestibulum ac odio ac. Risus lorem mauris. Proin enim tortor at erat dui.
    Aliquam magna condimentum. Orci donec morbi. Id justo at malesuada erat nulla urna quam eu nec elit commodo mi voluptatum gravida ante bibendum justo. Eleifend nec eget. Id massa quis eu vitae elit. Bibendum interdum semper. Donec libero duis. Phasellus
    malesuada adipiscing qui et eu. Justo egestas erat auctor sagittis sed nonummy amet dolor et in id. Ut blandit justo. Donec fringilla cursus enim velit ullamcorper. Pharetra eros mi eros accumsan dui. Pellentesque ipsum iaculis. Mi neque in nonummy
    venenatis vestibulum. Class egestas adipiscing nisl tellus quam ut in amet. Nostra nunc leo lorem eget ipsum elit eget metus nam sed pede. Nam nibh risus sit dui nullam. Consequat luctus tempus. Pede tellus eu mattis morbi donec. Natoque class leo.
    Ac lacus vestibulum ac odio ac. Risus lorem mauris. Proin enim tortor at erat dui. Aliquam magna condimentum. Orci donec morbi. Id justo at malesuada erat nulla urna quam eu nec elit commodo mi voluptatum gravida ante bibendum justo. Eleifend nec
    eget. Id massa quis eu vitae elit. Bibendum interdum semper. Donec libero duis. Phasellus malesuada adipiscing qui et eu. Justo egestas erat auctor sagittis sed nonummy amet dolor et in id. Ut blandit justo. Donec fringilla cursus enim velit ullamcorper.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you unfortunately this doesnt solve my issue. In my page it still doesnt stick at all

Comment: @Manny did you fix the errors in your HTML? As you can see this example works. So that means there is something else going on. You could try and replace your code with this and see what happens.